# In Perl, how can I tell if a string is a number?

Tags: perl

I am using Perl to convert some XML to JSON. If the XML attribute is a number, I don't want to put quotes around it so that JSON will treat it as a number and not a string. How can I tell if a Perl string is a number (contains only numbers 0 through 9 and possibly one decimal point)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [JSON specification](http://json.org) provides fairly clear rules on the format of a number, so the following regex should work:

```
/^-?(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/
```

Answer (score 21):

Try [`Scalar::Util::looks_like_number`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util):

E.g.:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

if (looks_like_number($thingy)) {
    print "looks like $thingy is a number...\n"
}
```

Comment: just realize that looks_like_number returns true for 'inf', 'nan', '1E02' and probably a few more strings that you might not expect to be numbers.

Comment: why would `1E02` not be a expected to be a number? it's scientific notation for 100.

Answer (score 4):

You could just force it into a number then compare that to the original string.

```
if( $value eq $value+0 ){
  print "$value is a number\n";
}
```

*( Note: it will only work for simple numbers, like 123 or 12.3 )*

Comment: Is "0" the same as "0e0" or "0.0" or "-0"?  Perl normally thinks so, but your test produces the opposite result.

Answer (score 3):

I think (from recent experiences) that you're making a mistake doing any kind of manual XML->JSON conversion.  I encountered many gotchas in the process, not least of which involved incorrectly escaped characters.

I would recommend parsing your XML with one of the many XML::* modules (I used XML::Simple) and then rendering it as JSON using JSON::XS.  JSON::XS allows you to convert a Perl data structure to JSON; XML::Simple parses XML to a Perl data structure.  In the mean time you can manipulate the Perl data structure as you wish.

Bottom line is that you no longer care about quoting/escaping characters.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't need to support unusual stuff (like sci-notation) this almost works (and is very simple):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $foo = '1234.5';

if( $foo =~ /\d+/ ){
    print "$foo is a number\n";
}
```

The reason it doesn't fully work is because you can have hyphens and dots anywhere (as many as you please) as long as you have at least one digit present). '--1--2' evaluates as zero, and '1.2.3.4.5' evals as 1.2 (the second dot and everything after are ignored). This may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number%2fwhole%2finteger%2ffloat%3f) question from perlfaq solves your problem.

Generally the problem is defining what exactly you want to read as number.

- is "-1.312" valid number?
- is "inf"?
- 5.34123412E-03 ?

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier for you to just read the XML into a data structure in Perl and let Perl's JSON library figure it out for you.  It already has checking for that, so unless your number is actually a string in the XML (e.g. it's got a space after it, etc) `JSON->encode()` will encode it as a JSON number.