# In Perl, how can I tell if a string is a number, but without using modules?

Tags: perl, variables, types

I have an array, each element is a string which consists of several words. The first word is identifier, which will not be considered. The rest part of the string would be number or alphabet only. I want to sort the alphabet part and then output the whole element. Following are my codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @log=("a1 9 2 3 1","gl cct car","zo4 4 7", "abl off key dog","a8 act zoo");

my @values;
my @letter_log;
my @letter_idf;
my @dig_log;
my $i;
$i=0;
foreach(@log)
{
  @values=split(/\s+/,$_);chomp(@values);
  @_= m/$values[0]\s/;
print "25 \$'=$';\n";
  if($' =~ /\D\s+/){$letter_idf[$i]=$values[0];$letter_log[$i]="$'";}
  else{$dig_log[$i]=$_;}

  $i++;
}

@_=sort { $letter_log[$a] cmp $letter_log[$b] } 0..$#letter_log;
chomp(@_);
enter code here
for($i=0;$i<=$#letter_log;$i++){print"$letter_idf[$_[$i]]"."$letter_log[$_[$i]];\t";}


foreach(@dig_log){print "$_;\t";}

print "\n";
```

I hope the output is like below

( "g1 act car";   "a8 act zoo";   "ab1 off key dog";   "a1 9 2 3 1";   "zo4 4 7")

However, my @letter_log is empty. I highly appreciate it if you could point out the errors and provide a correct solution.

PLEASE DO NOT USE MODULES, LIKE

```
import Scalar::Util qw(look_like_number);
```

I tried to avoid the modules because I want to study how to tell if a string is a number or not. Thanks!

Comment: if I use  "import Scalar::Util qw(look_like_number);", I can tell it.

Comment: As I mentioned, except for the first word, the rest of the element value would be alphabet or number only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112983/in-perl-how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-is-a-number?rq=1

Comment: My point is that I want to learn how to tell it without a module.

Comment: How do you understand my question? English is not my native language.

Comment: if I use a module, it can be realized. Following is the code.

Comment: import Scalar::Util qw(look_like_number);
if (looks_like_number(substr($', 1,1)){......}

Comment: You want to check if Perl would consider a string to be a number. Fixed the question.

Comment: It's not possible to implement `looks_like_number` exactly in Pure Perl. (But that wasn't your question)

Comment: You're asking us to translate 100s of lines of C code. That's not question.

Comment: "*I want to study how to tell if a string is a number*" - you "tell" by calling `looks_like_number`. Why do you insist on avoiding the actual solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments ikegami and melpomene.

The reason why I want to try it because the module is a "program" as well. I want to learn how to realize it by myself. After all, we meet all kinds of data which need to handle.

After many failures and tests, I figured it out and share it here.

first, the system variable "$'"changed before I assign it in if statement. I save it into another variable. 
Second, I use an alternative way to realize it because the sequence numbers with spaces must be string. So, I only take one "character" to test it. It proves that this operation is correct. Do not forget the statements in my original post

```
"The first word is identifier, which will not be considered. The rest part of the string would be number or alphabet only. "
```

Here are my revised scripts. "NOTHING IS IMPOSSIBLE."

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
#import Scalar::Util qw(look_like_number);

my @log=("a1 9 2 3 1","gl act car","zo4 4 7", "abl off key dog","a8 act zoo");
print "original log:\n";
$"=";\t";   #control array's delimiter
print "@log\n";

my @values;
my @letter_log;
my @letter_idf;
my @dig_log;
my $s;
my $i;
my $s_r;

$i=0;
foreach(@log)
{
  @values=split(/\s+/,$_);chomp(@values);
  @_= m/$values[0]\s/;
print "25 \$'=$';\n";
  $s=$';
  $s_r=substr($s,0,1);
  if($s_r =~ /\D/)  
  {  print"26.0: $'\ts=$s\ts_r=$s_r\n";    
     $letter_idf[$i]=$values[0];
     $letter_log[$i]=$s;
     print "26:  $letter_idf[$i]\t$letter_log[$i]\n";$i++;
  }
  else{$dig_log[$i]=$_;}
}

@_=sort { $letter_log[$a] cmp $letter_log[$b] } 0..$#letter_log;
chomp(@_);

print"35:  srt letter  log: @letter_log\n";
#foreach(@letter_log){print "$_;\t";}

print"38: nsrt letter log: ";
for($i=0;$i<=$#letter_log;$i++){print"$letter_idf[$_[$i]] "."$letter_log[$_[$i]];\t";}
print"\n";
print"41: digital log:";
foreach(@dig_log){print "$_;\t";}

print "\n";
```

Comment: That's not remotely close to checking if the value is something that Perl considers a number. There's so much it fails to consider numbers, including `-1` and `0.1`. Also, it considers some things numbers that Perl wouldn't, such as an empty string and `१` (U+0967 DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE)

Comment: you did not carefully read the condition, "The first word is identifier, which will not be considered. The rest part of the string would be number or alphabet only. "

Comment: for different formats of number(like 1.2, 35, 1e5), you still can test it. Randal L. Schwartz et. al. book has examples.

Answer (score 1):

The provided code that demonstrates your intention is not a perfect match for the title since it does a lot more. I would like to address only the main question in the title here.

If you can first define what a number is (instead of using a indirect definition of "whatever perl think a numbers is"), it becomes an easier problem.

For example, if you define the number you are looking for as a string with multiple characters of digit 0..9, then a simple regular expression `/^[0-9]+$/` can serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and answer. Yes. You are right. My tittle is focused on my question when I programmed. The codes are my practice.